# Adding XY coordinate to map in ArcGIS (not in dataset)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates

Is there a quick and easy way to add an XY coordinate in ArcGIS outside of creating a table?

A coworker just wants to see what that point is on a topo background.

I just want to see where a particular point is located without creating any data for it i.e. Just stored in a map document.

Comment: What is the point being added to?  Is supposed to be part of a point feature class in the end?  Or is it just a graphic point that is only stored in a map document?

Comment: Just stored in a map document. A coworker just wants to see what that point is on a topo background.

Comment: On the Tools toolbar there's a button "Go To XY" (looks like a point with XY written underneath it, in the same section as the search binocular button)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [Go To XY tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/using-the-go-to-xy-tool.htm) on the Tools toolbar that lets you enter an XY coordinate and see it as a graphic on the map.  The point can be shown by several different graphics (flash, point, labeled point, callout).